# Edit project option missing from VS2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Suddenly i cant see Edit project option in VS 2019. I can only see Edit Project item properties where i cant add `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`

This is what i see

[image]

Comment: Can you change the project when you "double click" the project? Projects might use the new "SDK" format, where you can open the `.csproj` file directly to edit the XML content.

Comment: @Progman no it doesnt work when i double click on project. It just collapses